# Continuously monitor linux console logs using C/C++ application

Tags: linux, console, stdout, stdin, popen

I have one third party library application which runs continuously and generates console print when some event occurs. 
I want to take some action when some specific event occurs so I need to monitor console prints continuously to trigget my action.

Is it possible to write application which can continuously monitor string dumper on console(stdout) and do processing when one line is detected.

I have tried to use 'popen' function but it keeps waiting until library application stops execution.
Here is my sample code using open

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fd = NULL;
    char buf[512] = {0};

    fd = popen ("./monitor","r");
    while (fgets (buf, 512, fd) != NULL)
    {
        printf ("__FILE__ : message : %s\n",buf);
    }

    printf ("EOF detected!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please let me know proper way of monitoring console logs and take action.

Thanks in advance.

Pratik

Comment: Have you thought about using bash/the shell to solve your problem?

Comment: hi sashang, can you provide some solution based on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example piece o code I 've written recently that reads from stdin and prints to stdout .

```
void echo(int bufferSize) {
    // Disable output buffering.
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    char buffer[bufferSize];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)) {

        printf("%s", buffer);
    }
}
```

As I understand you have a similar issue as I had initially getting delayed output because I didn't use:

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

You can also read from stdin(that's what my example code does ) just pipe your command to your c code or if you just want to filter output pipe it to grep. If it's a standardized syslog log you could also use tail on the log file:

```
tail -f <logfile>| <your c prgoramme>
```

or 
for just filering

```
tail -f <logfile>|grep "<your string here>"
```

or if without log file pipe stdout logs this way:

```
  <your app>|<your c prgoramme>
```

or

```
  <your app>| grep "<your string here>"
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I have one application which is continuously running and put print on console and wants to prepare other app which parse and take action on as per prints......I have tried 'setbuf' but it dosen't work. Tried <app1> | <app2> approach, it seems working for me, just problem is that my app2 get prints of app1 when app1 execution is completed.

Comment: but my code worked and Ihad this "print at the end" issuse before I added `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` or maybe you are doing  something differently have a look a the complete echo code[here](https://github.com/CySC/echo/tree/master/C) 
you can also download it and modify it according to your needs(since it's a really basic thing ) just echoes whatever comes to stdin

Comment: maybe your  problem is not in the output but  when reading  the input
maybe ` fgets (buf, 512, fd) ` is too big but still I am guessing too much because I don't know what is actually logged

Comment: Andreas, <app1> | <app2> approach worked my side now, i have just flushed stdout in app1 and problem is solved. Anyways thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: glad you made it work. The scenario where app1 doesn't flush was left out of the conversation xD(That will teach me not to take anything for granted-I took it for granted that it was an issue in app2 only and that app1 was outputting everything fine) I am still glad you got it working! :)

Answer (score 0):

3rd party program simulated by a shell script that writes to stdout

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    echo "something"
    sleep 2
done
```

You want to write something like this to capture the output from the 3rd party program and then act on the information:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
    if [[ $line == "something" ]]; then
        echo "do action here"
    fi
done
```

Then combine them with a pipe operator:

```
./dosomething.sh | act.sh
```

Comment: why not simply pipe to grep then ?

Comment: because he wants to do something after finding a string and continue reading from the input.